# Get newer MySQL Date in Bash-Script

Tags: mysql, bash, date, compare

I despair at a simple bash script.
So..
I've a MySQL Database running in two different databases there tables which should be synced with the same data - now I'm on a script which should do that for me.
In the tables theres a column "editeddate" which updates itself when sth edited in this row.
So the bash script is getting this.
i.e.
Table_A: *2015-01-09 18:08:54*
Table_B: *2015-01-09 18:10:09*
and now it won't say which of these strings **is newer**..
Here's the code snipped:

```
table_a=$(mysql -u UID -pPW -D DB -e "SELECT editeddate FROM table_a WHERE id=1" | sed '1d')    #gets sql data without columnname i.e. 2015-01-09 18:08:54
table_a_date=$(date -d "$table_a")                                                              #converts sql data in bash date
table_b=$(mysql -u UID -pPW -D DB -e "SELECT editeddate FROM table_b WHERE id=1" | sed '1d')    #gets sql data without columnname i.e. 2015-01-09 18:10:09
table_b_date=$(date -d "$table_b")                                                              #converts sql data in bash date

if [[ $table_a > $table_b_date ]];                                                              #if table_a is newer than table_b
then
    echo "table_a is newer"
elif [[ $table_a < $table_b_date ]];                                                            #otherwise if table_b is newer than table_a
then
    echo "table_b is newer"
else                                                                                            #else if both are the same
    echo "Nothing to is newer"
fi
```

**Thanks** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd bothered to see what your `date -d` call is spitting out, you'd see it's something like

```
Fri Jan  9 18:08:54 CST 2015
```

You're not comparing dates. You're comparing **STRINGS**, which means that "Wednesday" is **LARGER** than "Thursday", because W comes after T in the alphabet.

Yo
u'd have been fine if you were just comparing the raw `2015-01-09 ...` strings you're pulling out of the database, because that's a numeric string, in most-significant-first ordering.

Comment: So you say if levae the table_a_date and table_b_date and only compare the data from MySQL it should work?
EDIT: You're so right, Thanks a lot Marc! :)
Don't know why I didn't solve this myself